# correlation plot for many variables by group only in R

Tags: r

I need to make a correlation plot (something like what we get out of "corrplot" package), but I have too many variables and don't want to have all variables names on the plot. I want each variables from the same group to be next to each other with the group name over them (see an example of what I want in bottom).

my dataset looks like this

[image]

you can have it from here

```
sub_my_data <-
  structure(
    list(
      metabolites = c(
        "Acetate",
        "Acetoacetate",
        "Acetone",
        "Ala",
        "Albumin",
        "ApoA1",
        "ApoB",
        "ApoB_by_ApoA1",
        "bOHbutyrate",
        "Cholines",
        "Citrate",
        "Clinical_LDL_C",
        "Creatinine",
        "DHA",
        "Gln",
        "Glucose",
        "Gly",
        "GlycA",
        "HDL_C",
        "HDL_CE",
        "HDL_FC",
        "HDL_L",
        "HDL_P",
        "HDL_PL",
        "HDL_size",
        "HDL_TG",
        "His",
        "IDL_C",
        "IDL_CE",
        "IDL_FC",
        "IDL_L",
        "IDL_P",
        "IDL_PL",
        "IDL_TG",
        "Ile",
        "L_HDL_C",
        "L_HDL_CE",
        "L_HDL_FC",
        "L_HDL_L",
        "L_HDL_P",
        "L_HDL_PL",
        "L_HDL_TG",
        "L_LDL_C",
        "L_LDL_CE",
        "L_LDL_FC",
        "L_LDL_L",
        "L_LDL_P",
        "L_LDL_PL",
        "L_LDL_TG",
        "L_VLDL_C",
        "L_VLDL_CE",
        "L_VLDL_FC",
        "L_VLDL_L",
        "L_VLDL_P",
        "L_VLDL_PL",
        "L_VLDL_TG",
        "LA",
        "Lactate",
        "LDL_C",
        "LDL_CE",
        "LDL_FC",
        "LDL_L",
        "LDL_P",
        "LDL_PL",
        "LDL_size",
        "LDL_TG",
        "Leu",
        "M_HDL_C",
        "M_HDL_CE",
        "M_HDL_FC",
        "M_HDL_L",
        "M_HDL_P",
        "M_HDL_PL",
        "M_HDL_TG",
        "M_LDL_C",
        "M_LDL_CE",
        "M_LDL_FC",
        "M_LDL_L",
        "M_LDL_P",
        "M_LDL_PL",
        "M_LDL_TG",
        "M_VLDL_C",
        "M_VLDL_CE",
        "M_VLDL_FC",
        "M_VLDL_L",
        "M_VLDL_P",
        "M_VLDL_PL",
        "M_VLDL_TG",
        "MUFA",
        "non_HDL_C",
        "Omega_3",
        "Omega_6",
        "Phe",
        "Phosphatidylc",
        "Phosphoglyc",
        "PUFA",
        "Pyruvate",
        "Remnant_C",
        "S_HDL_C",
        "S_HDL_CE",
        "S_HDL_FC",
        "S_HDL_L",
        "S_HDL_P",
        "S_HDL_PL",
        "S_HDL_TG",
        "S_LDL_C",
        "S_LDL_CE",
        "S_LDL_FC",
        "S_LDL_L",
        "S_LDL_P",
        "S_LDL_PL",
        "S_LDL_TG",
        "S_VLDL_C",
        "S_VLDL_CE",
        "S_VLDL_FC",
        "S_VLDL_L",
        "S_VLDL_P",
        "S_VLDL_PL",
        "S_VLDL_TG",
        "SFA",
        "Sphingomyelins",
        "TG_by_PG",
        "Total_BCAA",
        "Total_C",
        "Total_CE",
        "Total_FA",
        "Total_FC",
        "Total_L",
        "Total_P",
        "Total_PL",
        "Total_TG",
        "Tyr",
        "Unsaturation",
        "Val",
        "VLDL_C",
        "VLDL_CE",
        "VLDL_FC",
        "VLDL_L",
        "VLDL_P",
        "VLDL_PL",
        "VLDL_size",
        "VLDL_TG",
        "XL_HDL_C",
        "XL_HDL_CE",
        "XL_HDL_FC",
        "XL_HDL_L",
        "XL_HDL_P",
        "XL_HDL_PL",
        "XL_HDL_TG",
        "XL_VLDL_C",
        "XL_VLDL_CE",
        "XL_VLDL_FC",
        "XL_VLDL_L",
        "XL_VLDL_P",
        "XL_VLDL_PL",
        "XL_VLDL_TG",
        "XS_VLDL_C",
        "XS_VLDL_CE",
        "XS_VLDL_FC",
        "XS_VLDL_L",
        "XS_VLDL_P",
        "XS_VLDL_PL",
        "XS_VLDL_TG",
        "XXL_VLDL_C",
        "XXL_VLDL_CE",
        "XXL_VLDL_FC",
        "XXL_VLDL_L",
        "XXL_VLDL_P",
        "XXL_VLDL_PL",
        "XXL_VLDL_TG"
      ),
      Group = c(
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Amino acids",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Apolipoproteins",
        "Apolipoproteins",
        "Apolipoproteins",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Other lipids",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Cholesterol",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Fatty acids",
        "Glycolysis related metabolites",
        "Fluid balance",
        "Glycolysis related metabolites",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Cholesterol",
        "Cholesteryl esters",
        "Free cholesterol",
        "Total lipids",
        "Lipoprotein particle concentrations",
        "Phospholipids",
        "Lipoprotein particle sizes",
        "Triglycerides",
        "Glycolysis related metabolites",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Glycolysis related metabolites",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Fatty acids",
        "Fluid balance",
        "Cholesterol",
        "Cholesteryl esters",
        "Free cholesterol",
        "Total lipids",
        "Lipoprotein particle concentrations",
        "Phospholipids",
        "Lipoprotein particle sizes",
        "Triglycerides",
        "Ketone bodies",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Fatty acids",
        "Cholesterol",
        "Fatty acids",
        "Fatty acids",
        "Ketone bodies",
        "Other lipids",
        "Other lipids",
        "Fatty acids",
        "Inflammation",
        "Cholesterol",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Fatty acids",
        "Other lipids",
        "Other lipids",
        "Glycolysis related metabolites",
        "Cholesterol",
        "Cholesteryl esters",
        "Fatty acids",
        "Free cholesterol",
        "Total lipids",
        "Lipoprotein particle concentrations",
        "Phospholipids",
        "Triglycerides",
        "Ketone bodies",
        "Fatty acids",
        "Ketone bodies",
        "Cholesterol",
        "Cholesteryl esters",
        "Free cholesterol",
        "Total lipids",
        "Lipoprotein particle concentrations",
        "Phospholipids",
        "Lipoprotein particle sizes",
        "Triglycerides",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses",
        "Lipoprotein subclasses"
      ),
      V1 = c(
        0.44,
        0.08,
        0.11,
        0.42,
        0.58,
        0.34,
        0.22,
        0.23,
        0.12,
        0.28,
        0.34,
        0.29,
        0.56,
        0.43,
        0.43,
        0.25,
        0.62,
        0.18,
        0.37,
        0.39,
        0.33,
        0.34,
        0.35,
        0.34,
        0.39,
        0.18,
        0.51,
        0.31,
        0.3,
        0.32,
        0.25,
        0.16,
        0.21,
        0.06,
        0.51,
        0.4,
        0.42,
        0.36,
        0.38,
        0.38,
        0.38,
        0.14,
        0.31,
        0.31,
        0.35,
        0.28,
        0.23,
        0.28,
        0.06,
        0.16,
        0.19,
        0.13,
        0.1,
        0.09,
        0.1,
        0.09,
        0.14,
        0.4,
        0.3,
        0.29,
        0.34,
        0.27,
        0.24,
        0.28,
        0.63,
        0.06,
        0.73,
        0.4,
        0.42,
        0.35,
        0.4,
        0.39,
        0.4,
        0.2,
        0.29,
        0.26,
        0.35,
        0.27,
        0.27,
        0.28,
        0.07,
        0.25,
        0.26,
        0.22,
        0.18,
        0.22,
        0.2,
        0.12,
        0.11,
        0.24,
        0.3,
        0.19,
        0.54,
        0.31,
        0.3,
        0.21,
        0.2,
        0.17,
        0.49,
        0.6,
        0.32,
        0.35,
        0.47,
        0.35,
        0.18,
        0.27,
        0.24,
        0.37,
        0.25,
        0.22,
        0.25,
        0.05,
        0.19,
        0.18,
        0.23,
        0.16,
        0.15,
        0.21,
        0.15,
        0.15,
        0.27,
        0.1,
        0.69,
        0.3,
        0.31,
        0.16,
        0.23,
        0.22,
        0.34,
        0.27,
        0.07,
        0.49,
        0.57,
        0.74,
        0.16,
        0.17,
        0.15,
        0.1,
        0.14,
        0.12,
        0.36,
        0.07,
        0.35,
        0.36,
        0.3,
        0.32,
        0.31,
        0.32,
        0.1,
        0.12,
        0.17,
        0.09,
        0.08,
        0.08,
        0.08,
        0.07,
        0.13,
        0.16,
        0.07,
        0.08,
        0.09,
        0.05,
        0.12,
        0.03,
        0.01,
        0.05,
        0.03,
        0.02,
        0.03,
        0.04
      ),
      V2 = c(
        0.48,
        0,
        0.38,
        0.18,
        0.25,
        0.5,
        0.16,
        0.12,
        0.6,
        0.43,
        0.5,
        0.09,
        0.3,
        0.29,
        0.09,
        0.22,
        0.46,
        0.21,
        0.45,
        0.45,
        0.47,
        0.51,
        0.41,
        0.55,
        0.55,
        0.52,
        0.08,
        0.17,
        0.17,
        0.17,
        0.18,
        0.06,
        0.19,
        0.38,
        0.06,
        0.51,
        0.52,
        0.49,
        0.53,
        0.52,
        0.56,
        0.42,
        0.15,
        0.17,
        0.13,
        0.15,
        0.19,
        0.09,
        0.33,
        0.25,
        0.27,
        0.22,
        0.19,
        0.19,
        0.23,
        0.17,
        0.26,
        0.35,
        0.15,
        0.17,
        0.09,
        0.15,
        0.17,
        0.11,
        0.75,
        0.35,
        0.08,
        0.5,
        0.51,
        0.49,
        0.57,
        0.54,
        0.61,
        0.55,
        0.14,
        0.16,
        0.09,
        0.16,
        0.12,
        0.14,
        0.35,
        0.16,
        0.12,
        0.2,
        0.23,
        0.22,
        0.22,
        0.24,
        0.38,
        0.14,
        0.42,
        0.36,
        0.13,
        0.51,
        0.49,
        0.38,
        0.12,
        0.13,
        0.38,
        0.46,
        0.41,
        0.43,
        0.4,
        0.49,
        0.45,
        0.14,
        0.16,
        0.07,
        0.16,
        0.18,
        0.15,
        0.28,
        0.22,
        0.23,
        0.21,
        0.3,
        0.3,
        0.26,
        0.4,
        0.33,
        0.24,
        0.28,
        0.11,
        0.23,
        0.24,
        0.38,
        0.2,
        0.29,
        0.39,
        0.4,
        0.25,
        0.16,
        0.46,
        0.16,
        0.21,
        0.19,
        0.23,
        0.21,
        0.26,
        0.24,
        0.44,
        0.21,
        0.42,
        0.44,
        0.34,
        0.44,
        0.43,
        0.46,
        0.35,
        0.21,
        0.22,
        0.19,
        0.19,
        0.2,
        0.19,
        0.2,
        0.18,
        0.17,
        0.2,
        0.24,
        0.22,
        0.25,
        0.48,
        0.18,
        0.15,
        0.21,
        0.17,
        0.18,
        0.19,
        0.16
      ),
      V3 = c(
        0.66,
        0,
        0.25,
        0.21,
        0.31,
        0.74,
        0.31,
        0.14,
        0.48,
        0.66,
        0.43,
        0.36,
        0.37,
        0.45,
        0.31,
        0.2,
        1,
        0.29,
        0.72,
        0.71,
        0.74,
        0.76,
        0.66,
        0.8,
        0.65,
        0.49,
        0.3,
        0.48,
        0.47,
        0.49,
        0.47,
        0.31,
        0.46,
        0.39,
        0.08,
        0.74,
        0.74,
        0.71,
        0.76,
        0.73,
        0.81,
        0.48,
        0.43,
        0.43,
        0.44,
        0.42,
        0.31,
        0.38,
        0.38,
        0.15,
        0.19,
        0.12,
        0.09,
        0.09,
        0.11,
        0.06,
        0.36,
        0.37,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.41,
        0.39,
        0.31,
        0.36,
        0.66,
        0.37,
        0.13,
        0.75,
        0.75,
        0.76,
        0.8,
        0.77,
        0.84,
        0.52,
        0.36,
        0.35,
        0.37,
        0.35,
        0.31,
        0.32,
        0.36,
        0.3,
        0.31,
        0.28,
        0.22,
        0.25,
        0.26,
        0.13,
        0.36,
        0.36,
        0.41,
        0.45,
        0.16,
        0.72,
        0.7,
        0.47,
        0.12,
        0.31,
        0.58,
        0.61,
        0.64,
        0.57,
        0.57,
        0.63,
        0.34,
        0.31,
        0.3,
        0.36,
        0.32,
        0.29,
        0.34,
        0.22,
        0.27,
        0.26,
        0.3,
        0.28,
        0.26,
        0.3,
        0.28,
        0.42,
        0.55,
        0.1,
        0.14,
        0.53,
        0.54,
        0.43,
        0.45,
        0.48,
        0.64,
        0.65,
        0.16,
        0.19,
        0.47,
        0.17,
        0.25,
        0.26,
        0.22,
        0.15,
        0.27,
        0.2,
        0.21,
        0.09,
        0.6,
        0.62,
        0.52,
        0.6,
        0.59,
        0.61,
        0.38,
        0.13,
        0.17,
        0.09,
        0.07,
        0.08,
        0.08,
        0.06,
        0.37,
        0.39,
        0.32,
        0.35,
        0.34,
        0.31,
        0.43,
        0.05,
        0.03,
        0.08,
        0.03,
        0.04,
        0.05,
        0.02
      ),
      V4 = c(
        0.66,
        0.14,
        0.14,
        0.43,
        0.38,
        0.3,
        0.28,
        0.31,
        0.15,
        0.28,
        0.47,
        0.38,
        0.22,
        0.23,
        0.07,
        0.28,
        0.5,
        0.51,
        0.32,
        0.33,
        0.28,
        0.28,
        0.32,
        0.28,
        0.31,
        0.16,
        0.29,
        0.39,
        0.37,
        0.41,
        0.32,
        0.26,
        0.29,
        0.07,
        0.41,
        0.32,
        0.33,
        0.3,
        0.3,
        0.3,
        0.3,
        0.1,
        0.38,
        0.37,
        0.43,
        0.35,
        0.31,
        0.37,
        0.09,
        0.18,
        0.22,
        0.14,
        0.09,
        0.08,
        0.11,
        0.06,
        0.21,
        0.53,
        0.37,
        0.35,
        0.43,
        0.35,
        0.31,
        0.36,
        0.73,
        0.09,
        0.5,
        0.35,
        0.38,
        0.3,
        0.35,
        0.34,
        0.35,
        0.18,
        0.35,
        0.31,
        0.44,
        0.34,
        0.29,
        0.36,
        0.1,
        0.32,
        0.35,
        0.27,
        0.19,
        0.25,
        0.24,
        0.08,
        0.21,
        0.31,
        0.1,
        0.26,
        0.37,
        0.25,
        0.29,
        0.24,
        0.34,
        0.25,
        0.52,
        0.64,
        0.31,
        0.37,
        0.51,
        0.37,
        0.2,
        0.34,
        0.31,
        0.44,
        0.31,
        0.28,
        0.31,
        0.07,
        0.25,
        0.24,
        0.28,
        0.17,
        0.15,
        0.24,
        0.09,
        0.17,
        0.36,
        0.08,
        0.47,
        0.34,
        0.36,
        0.21,
        0.28,
        0.25,
        0.32,
        0.29,
        0.06,
        0.93,
        0.48,
        0.47,
        0.22,
        0.23,
        0.2,
        0.11,
        0.17,
        0.16,
        0.36,
        0.05,
        0.31,
        0.32,
        0.29,
        0.28,
        0.27,
        0.27,
        0.06,
        0.16,
        0.22,
        0.11,
        0.09,
        0.09,
        0.11,
        0.06,
        0.18,
        0.21,
        0.12,
        0.12,
        0.14,
        0.1,
        0.11,
        0.08,
        0.06,
        0.1,
        0.08,
        0.06,
        0.09,
        0.08
      ),
      V5 = c(
        0.44,
        0.36,
        0.06,
        0.55,
        0.79,
        0.57,
        0.2,
        0.13,
        0.16,
        0.45,
        0.55,
        0.27,
        0.24,
        0.44,
        0.15,
        0.17,
        0.47,
        0.62,
        0.59,
        0.6,
        0.55,
        0.59,
        0.53,
        0.61,
        0.55,
        0.26,
        0.34,
        0.34,
        0.32,
        0.36,
        0.3,
        0.13,
        0.27,
        0.18,
        0.35,
        0.61,
        0.62,
        0.56,
        0.6,
        0.57,
        0.63,
        0.24,
        0.28,
        0.28,
        0.32,
        0.27,
        0.22,
        0.27,
        0.19,
        0.13,
        0.15,
        0.1,
        0.08,
        0.07,
        0.08,
        0.07,
        0.21,
        0.58,
        0.28,
        0.27,
        0.3,
        0.26,
        0.23,
        0.26,
        0.68,
        0.19,
        0.36,
        0.63,
        0.64,
        0.59,
        0.64,
        0.62,
        0.68,
        0.28,
        0.28,
        0.27,
        0.29,
        0.27,
        0.25,
        0.24,
        0.19,
        0.23,
        0.26,
        0.19,
        0.16,
        0.19,
        0.17,
        0.1,
        0.23,
        0.23,
        0.31,
        0.29,
        0.39,
        0.41,
        0.46,
        0.3,
        0.36,
        0.19,
        0.55,
        0.63,
        0.46,
        0.47,
        0.53,
        0.51,
        0.2,
        0.25,
        0.23,
        0.31,
        0.23,
        0.19,
        0.22,
        0.12,
        0.17,
        0.15,
        0.19,
        0.15,
        0.14,
        0.19,
        0.17,
        0.27,
        0.51,
        0.08,
        0.38,
        0.36,
        0.38,
        0.28,
        0.29,
        0.31,
        0.5,
        0.44,
        0.09,
        0.39,
        0.6,
        0.41,
        0.16,
        0.16,
        0.15,
        0.1,
        0.15,
        0.12,
        0.27,
        0.07,
        0.49,
        0.51,
        0.42,
        0.48,
        0.45,
        0.47,
        0.18,
        0.1,
        0.13,
        0.08,
        0.06,
        0.07,
        0.07,
        0.05,
        0.18,
        0.21,
        0.14,
        0.15,
        0.15,
        0.12,
        0.22,
        0.06,
        0.03,
        0.09,
        0.06,
        0.05,
        0.06,
        0.07
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-170L)
  )
```

columns with names Va, V2, ...etc represent participants.

I tried this code but it gave me a missy plot with group name repeated on each variable

```
sub_my_data<-  sub_my_data[,-1]

tra3<- t( sub_my_data)

rownames(tra3) <- NULL



colnames(tra3) <- tra3[1,]
tra3 <- tra3[-1, ] 
tra3<- as.data.frame(tra3)
str(tra3)
names(tra3)

for (t in 1:170) {
  tra3[,t]<-as.numeric(tra3[,t])
}


tiff('metabolites correlation plot2.jpg', width = 5000, height = 6000, res=300)


corrplot(cor(tra3))


dev.off()
```

But, it didn't work!

the wish to have something like this
[image]

thank you in advance!

Comment: You have 170 observations, it will be hard to make a clear plot from this dataset. Don't you have other alternatives ? Otherwise just `try sub_my_data<-  sub_my_data[order(sub_my_data$Group),];sub_my_data$metabolites=factor(sub_my_data$metabolites,levels=sub_my_data$metabolites);sub_my_data<-  sub_my_data[,-2]` and after take you code since `tra3<- t( sub_my_data)` but with your number of observations you will struggle to obtain something meaningful

Comment: I have too many participants but to make it short I added a few here. the plot will be meaningful because I want it to show general idea of correlation between groups.

Comment: Just try with my code, maybe my eyes are not good enough, but I think this is a bad representation already with 100 observations

Comment: I tried your code but it does the same issue (repeat the group name over each variable) resulting in a plot with overlapping names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not really convinced by the representation but here is some hints to make it look like as you want :

```
sub_my_data<-  sub_my_data[order(sub_my_data$Group),]
sub_my_data$metabolites=factor(sub_my_data$metabolites,levels=sub_my_data$metabolites)
Group=table(sub_my_data$Group)
sub_my_data<-  sub_my_data[,-2]

tra3<- t( sub_my_data)

rownames(tra3) <- NULL



colnames(tra3) <- tra3[1,]
tra3 <- tra3[-1, ] 
tra3<- as.data.frame(tra3)
str(tra3)
names(tra3)

for (t in 1:170) {
  tra3[,t]<-as.numeric(tra3[,t])
}
par(mar=c(5,5,5,5),xpd=NA)
corrplot(cor(tra3),tl.pos='n',mar=c(5,5,5,5))
n=sum(Group)
for (k in 1:length(names(Group))){
mtext(text = names(Group)[k], side = 2, line = -2.5, at = n-(Group[[k]]/2), las = 1,cex=0.5 )
  n=n-Group[[k]]
}
n=0
for (k in 1:length(names(Group))){
  text(labels = names(Group)[k], y=sum(Group)+1, x = n+(Group[[k]]/2),srt = 90,adj=0,cex=0.5)
  n=n+Group[[k]]
}
```

You will need to work around parameters to make it adapted to your R session, notably margins.
With mtext and text, I add the label Group at the middle of the cluster of samples related to the Group.
Let's imagine you could add some bars to distinguish the clusters afterwards, you can adapt it as you want but this is basis because there is no options with corrplot() to make it as you want : you will need to adapt it with custom code lines.

[image]